# Problem with understanding the circuit related to stable matching security

Tags: multiplexer, encoder, security

I am trying to understand a circuit used for stable matching. The paper title is:
MPCircuits: Optimized Circuit Generation for Secure Multi-Party Computation and is available :

[here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/275.pdf)

I am attaching the image:

[image: stable matching multi-party secure circuit]

I have following questions:

1. why Preference of group1 starts from L_0 where as preference list from group2 starts with L_(n/2+1)?
2. Any reason why they used the priority encoder?
3. What is the technique for the security of preference list?

Somebody please guide me.

Comment: Might this be better asked over on security.se?

Comment: Is there any example for secure stable matching circuitry?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea.  That said, I know enough about crypto to be dangerous and here's my take on it.  The circuit you're asking about appears to describe the realization in silicon of a particular crypto system (a type of [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) to be specific).  The items you're asking about relate to the design of the algorithm being used and not the specific physical (electronic) components being used to implement it.  Thus I think you're far more likely to get a useful/any answer over on the sister site.

Comment: We have two groups. Why we call it a multi-party circuit?